# Get login time for Windows user in Java

Tags: java, windows, userinfo

Is there a way in Java to get the time when the current user logged in?

I know that if you run `quser` in Windows terminal, it will list some basic information about current users, including `LOGON TIME`, with minute precision.

Is there a System property or something I can access in Java which I can get the user's login time from?

Bonus points if there's a cross-platform way to get the current user's login time in Windows, Mac OS, Android, etc.

Comment: Can't you create a code snippet that will run `quser` on a shell? [This link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) provides an example on how to execute a shell command from java.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no java System property that can retrieve a login time. There is one that can get the currently logged in user but not anything more specific than that. You could try what @robotlos suggested; I don't know how you would extract that value to use in your program afterwards, though, but maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution could be using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` like so:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process p;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("quser");
        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

Was able to successfully get my login info:

```
run:

 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 robotlos              console             1  Active    1+18:08  3/17/2016 10:36 AM

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

To determine what OS is being used you can use `System.getProperty("os.name")`

To isolate the date and time, in my case since it's the last 3 substrings of `sb` you could do something like:

```
 String[] vals = sb.toString().split(" ");
 String loginTime = vals[vals.length - 3] + " " + vals[vals.length - 2] + " " + vals[vals.length - 1];
```

And while it's not the prettiest solution,

```
System.out.println(loginTime);
```

will print out:

```
3/17/2016 10:36 AM
```

Comment: Did you succeed to parse that value to `Date` using local windows datetime format?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou not sure what you're asking. But in regards to platforms, this was run on Windows.

Comment: I meant to return `Date`, not `String`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou oh, I don't think there's an issue with that since I'm appending to a `String`. I'm not really parsing anything.

Comment: besides, there is an issue. I failed to find a solution to read machine-local datetime pattern other than to read windows registry...

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I'm not really following what youre trying to get across.

Comment: `3/17/2016 10:36 AM` is a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), I try to convert it to [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou You can do: `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);` and then `Date date = format.parse(loginTime);`. If you `System.out.println(date);` you get: `Thu Mar 17 10:36:00 PDT 2016`

Comment: I know how to use SimpleDateFormat, thank you :) I was asking how you get the pattern used there. Because on you  machine it is `M/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa`, on my machine it is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` and on another machine it may be other, depending on OS settings, and it doesn't refer to default Java pattern.